# AngularJS app template with user registration and login

Tags: angularjs, user-management, login

I am concerned about security, and will never really 100% trust any security mechanism coded by me :-/

Does anyone know of an AngularJS app template with user registration and login? ("Forgot password" would be a nice bonus.)

If the user tries to visit any part of the app without being logged in, he should be redirected to the Register/Login screen.

I suspect that such an AngularJS SPA would have to come with matching server-side code. If so, I have a preference for PHP over Node.js.